# what i am doing wrong in calculating quartiles

Tags: descriptive-statistics, percentile, quantile

can somebody  please help me to understand? Why 1st quartile  in this data is equal 4.5 and 3rd quartile is equal 6.5.

I am getting 4.25 and 6.25 , but not 4.5 and not 6.5. I use formula (n+1)/4 for the first quartile and 3/4(n+1) for the 3rd quartile. 
For the 1st quartile :(8+1)/4= 9/4 = 2 1/4, so the Q1 is the second number and the quarter way forward. or 4.25

2 4 5 6 6 6 7 8

What am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first quartile should have at least $\frac14$ of the data points at or below it
and at least $\frac34$ of the data points at or above it.
In the case where the number of data points is divisible by $4$, there can be a
gap between the greatest value in the first $\frac14$ of the data points
and the least value in the last $\frac34$ of the data points,
and then there is a convention to put the first quartile midway between those two points.

For the first quartile, then, if there are $n$ data points then you can
compute $k = \frac n4$. If $k$ is an integer, you count off $k$
values starting with the smallest, and put $Q_1$ midway between the $k$th
value and the $(k + 1)$th value.
If $k$ is not an integer, you count off $\lfloor k \rfloor$ data points
and $Q_1$ is the next data point.

The third quartile works similarly, but with $k = \frac 34 n$ instead of $\frac n4$.

It's important to remember that $n$ in these formulas is *not* one of the data values,
and you do not *add* the result of $\frac n4$ to any data value; you use $\frac n4$ to
*count* data values.

It's not clear where you got the formulas $\frac14(n+1)$ or $\frac34(n+1)$.
Perhaps they were intended to work with a data set labeled
$y_0, y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$, which actually has $n+1$ data points
because its first data point is $y_0$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is much clearer now. I have used the  formulas with the same rules as the Minitab software uses. But I wanted to practice more, and used samples from different sources that use different rules, so I got different answers and was not sure why. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Many different formulas for quantiles (including quartiles) are
in common use. That is because quantiles are used with many 
different distributions and for many different purposes.

In particular, major statistical software packages disagree
on which methods to implement as their default: (a) SAS, (b)
Minitab and SPSS, and (c) R (and its parent S) use three
different methods. Furthermore, these methods differ from
methods found in reputable elementary texts, including
the method mentioned in the Answer by @David K. (Adding to the confusion:
Tukey's 'fourths', sometimes used in making
boxplots and often considered essentially the same as quartiles,
use yet other criteria.)

Generally speaking the differences among these methods become
negligible for large sample sizes. However, there can be marked
differences for small samples. Fortunately, it is for large
samples that quantiles make the most sense. (Roughly,
quartiles are intended to divide a sample into four 'chunks'
of equal size: how do you do that with a sample of size 10?)

Here is a demo using R software, which allows use of the
parameter `type` to change its default method. By default
the R function `quantile` gives min, lower quartile, median,
upper quartile, max. (Parameters can be used to specify other
quantiles as desired.)

```
 x = round(rnorm(10, 100, 15), 1)  # 10 obs. from NORM(100, 15) rounded to 1 place.
 sort(x)
 ## 73.7  81.5  83.5  96.3 104.6 106.2 113.8 114.2 116.4 117.4

 quantile(x)  # R default
 ##    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 ##  73.7  86.7 105.4 114.1 117.4 

 quantile(x, type=3)  # as in SAS
 ##    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 ##  73.7  81.5 104.6 114.2 117.4

 quantile(x, type=6)  # as in Minitab & SPSS
 ##    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
 ## 73.70  83.00 105.40 114.75 117.40 

 fivenum(x)  # Tukey's 'fourths' (actual sample values, not strictly quartiles)
 ##  73.7  83.5  105.4  114.2  117.4
```

---

```
 x = round(rnorm(1000, 100, 15), 1)  # n = 1000;  all about the same
 # 111.4 repeated

 quantile(x)
 ##    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
 ## 57.60  89.45  99.85 111.40 153.70 

 quantile(x, type=3)
 ##    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
 ##  57.6  89.3  99.8 111.4 153.7 

 quantile(x, type=6)
 ##    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
 ## 57.60  89.35  99.85 111.40 153.70 

 fivenum(x)
 ##  57.60   89.40   99.85  111.40  153.70
```

If you have access to R (available free from `www.r-project.org`), you can
type `? quantile` and read some details of nine different
types of quantiles--about halfway down the page.